# Construct splitting field of $x^3+x^2+x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z_3}$

Tags: field-theory

Construct splitting field of $$x^3+x^2+x+2$$ over $\mathbb{Z_3}$.

PS: let $\alpha$ is a solution of, then I can't guess another solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Every finite extension of a finite field is a normal extension. Does this help?

Comment: Hint #1: How do you normally solve a cubic equation that you know a root of? Hint #2: You know an automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the polynomial is cubic, if it is reducible, it must have a linear factor (why?); therefore, it suffices to check it has no roots in $\Bbb Z_3$. This is easy to check, and we find $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=2$, and $f(2)=1$. This shows that $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_3$.

Using the fact that every finite extension of a finite field is normal (meaning that if $g$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3$ and has a root in some extension, then that extension contains all of the roots of $g$). Now we know the extension has degree $3$ since $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3$, so the extension is $\Bbb Z_3(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the polynomial is irreducible, the splitting field is just $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] / (x^3 + x^2 + x + 2)$